# SDKManager doesn't show available updates

Tags: android

I have `sdk_tools` v25.2.5 installed.

I start the standalone `sdkmanager` GUI with:

```
$ ./my_android_sdk/tools/android sdk
```

The GUI doesn't show that there is an update for SDK Tools available.

But when I run

```
$ ./my_android_sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --list
```

The output is

```
Available Updates:
  ID                                               | Installed | Available
  -------                                          | -------   | -------  
  tools                                            | 25.2.5    | 26.1.1
```

This seems to be a bug.

Comment: Thats not an update! Its a completely different version! You have to install the verison 26.1.1 independently. It would have been an update and a bug if it was still 25. May be from 25.2.5 to 25.3.1!

Comment: It seems a bug, to me. `26.1.1` actually **is an update**, in regards to any lower version. In facts, it is listed in the updates list.